# Checking OS version

Tags: vbscript

Hi I'm having trouble understanding this code. Can someone help me explain what it does?

```
GetOperatingSystemVersion
If OSVersion > 6.0 Then
strCMD = "c:\Windows\System32\manage-bde.exe "
Else
strCMD = "cscript.exe c:\Windows\System32\manage-bde.wsf "
End If`

Sub GetOperatingSystemVersion

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set oss = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")`
For Each os in oss
OSVersion = Left(os.Version,3)
OSVersion = Round(OSVersion,3)
Next

End Sub
```

From my understanding, it will call GetOperatingSystemVersion and check the for loop. That's the part I don't understand. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it uses [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx) to retrieve the operating system version.

The first two lines are just standard WMI-from-VBScript idioms. You'll find plenty of sample code and information on this online if you run a keyword search. The important part is `Win32_OperatingSystem`, which specifies the WMI class to query. Plugging that into MSDN, you'll find [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239.aspx), including a list of the properties and methods exposed by that class.

Putting it all together, then, the syntax `Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem` is a query that retrieves all instances of the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class, including all members of that class.

The `For Each` loop loops through all of the items in the returned collection, one at a time. For the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class, this is not strictly necessary, as there should only be one global object returned. But VBScript (at least prior to Vista) didn't have any way of accessing a particular item in a collection, so you had to do it this way.

Inside of the `For Each` loop, the `os` object variable refers to an instance of the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class, which as [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239.aspx) reveals, exposes a `Version` member, which returns a string. This member is queried, and the `Left` function extracts the first 3 characters from its left-hand side. These 3 characters are stored in the `OSVersion` variable.

This is necessary because modern versions of Windows include the build number as part of the version number, resulting in a string that looks something like `6.1.7601` or `5.1.2600`. The code that's going to use the version number apparently doesn't care about the build number; it just wants the major and minor version number, so it only extracts the first 3 characters from the version field.

Finally, the 3 characters stored in the `OSVersion` variable are rounded to 3 decimal places using the `Round` function, and the result is saved back into the `OSVersion` variable. Since it only extracted the first 3 characters from the version field, I have no idea why it's doing this.

So when the function finishes, the `OSVersion` variable contains the current version of the operating system, rounded to 3 decimal places. The code is fragile, though, and must be carefully maintained. What happens when Microsoft releases a version of Windows with the version number `6.10.xxxx`? (Answer: This code calls it version `6.1`.)

Comment: Wow, thanks cody for the quick reply. Now I understand what the function does. Thank you very much sir!